Difficulty understanding .moveaxis in Numpy
I am having difficulties understanding .moveaxis in Numpy.
I first create an array by using a=np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4). The system will first fill up axis 2 with 0 1 2 3, then move along axis 1 to the next row. When the first 'page' is done, the system move along axis 0. The following is obtained.
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])

If I input b = np.swapaxes(a,0,2); b now, the system should fill up axis 0 first, then axis 1 and finally axis 2. The following is obtained.
array([[[ 0, 12],
        [ 4, 16],
        [ 8, 20]],

       [[ 1, 13],
        [ 5, 17],
        [ 9, 21]],

       [[ 2, 14],
        [ 6, 18],
        [10, 22]],

       [[ 3, 15],
        [ 7, 19],
        [11, 23]]])

This is understandable as axis 1 is preserved, so we can still see columns like 0 4 8 and 1 5 9 after swapping the axes.
But I don't really understand how .moveaxis works. If I input b = np.moveaxis(a,0,2); b, the following is obtained.
array([[[ 0, 12],
        [ 1, 13],
        [ 2, 14],
        [ 3, 15]],

       [[ 4, 16],
        [ 5, 17],
        [ 6, 18],
        [ 7, 19]],

       [[ 8, 20],
        [ 9, 21],
        [10, 22],
        [11, 23]]])

I know that the .moveaxis function is meant to 'move axis 0 to a new position while the other axes remain the same order', but what is the meaning of that? I understand that the result should be an array with shape (3, 4, 2), but why would the system go down the first column in the first place then move on to the second page?

You asked for help on understanding the mechanism behind .moveaxis.
The documentation explains it twice,
imprecisely in English and
very precisely in code when you click on [source].
There's not a lot going on there.
We just pick a new ordering of the existing axes,
specified by the caller.
    order = [n for n in range(a.ndim) if n not in source]

    for dest, src in sorted(zip(destination, source)):
        order.insert(dest, src)

And then the final assignment essentially computes np.transpose(order),
so that's the method you want to study in order to better understand
this function.
Recall that
.rollaxis()
is being deprecated, with
.moveaxis()
offering a superset of its functionality.
Studying the subset might prove helpful to you.

This is still not answering my question. If we move axis 0 to the last place, shouldn't the system fill up the array along axis 0 first? Why does it fill in the array along axis 1 first?
